# Как в ассемблере посчитать количество бит необходимых под число?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

В моем коде на fasm выполняются различные арифметические операции над числами, введенными с консоли. Как посчитать количество бит, необходимое под результат? Например число 12 уместится в 5 бит (промежуток от -16 до 15). И как сохранить число в оперативной памяти, если оно выходит за пределы двойного слова?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: если число выходит за пределы двойного слова, можно использовать четвертное слово или два двойных. А кол-во бит - тут очень похоже на находждение первого единичного бита

Comment: А каким образом нужно использовать два двойных слова?

Comment: точно также как одно. Просто чуточку больше памяти нужно. Два двойных слова - это просто массив на 2 элемента

Comment: Понял. Сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: У меня получилось сделать сложение. Только как теперь вывести число на консоль? Я всегда использовал printf, а он принимает двойное слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

необходимо использовать команду *bsr* указанная команда вернет номер старшего бита числа установленного в 1 (единицу), в случае числа 12 это будет число 3.